# Is it possible to remove the 'Parallelizable' attribute programatically from a test fixture in NUnit 3.0?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I currently have '[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]' set up for each test fixture to run them in parallel. I want to be able to add an option for the user to run test fixtures parallely or sequentially. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the command line, pass the command line option, `--workers=1` to run with one thread.